# Splitting by particular punctuation

Tags: python, string, split

Let's assume that I want to remove a comma from a sentence, but in this particular way.

```
 I ate pineapples, grapes -> I ate pineapples I ate grapes

 we know python 2.0, 3.0 well -> we know python 2.0 well we know python 3.0 well
```

Basically, I want to keep everything where comma didn't happen. Is there an easy way to do it using 're' library in python?

Comment: You probably want to do a string replace. No need for regex.

Comment: @SumnerEvans . spring replace only allows for "pineapples, grapes -> pineapples grapes" I was wondering if there's way to split it like above.

Comment: You are going to have to define what to do about sentences like this: "I ate pineapples, grapes, and bananas". Does it go to "I ate pineapples I ate grapes I ate and bananas"? Also, what do you want to happen when there is a phrase? For example, with your current definition, "I ate great pineapples, amazing grapes" would turn into "I ate great pineapples grapes I ate great amazing grapes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re basically splitting the string by a coma, keeping the first sentence but repeating it replacing the last word of the first sentence with the words after the coma.

```
s = "I ate pineapples, grapes"

s1 = "we know python 2.0, 3.0 well"

def my_split(string):
    sep = string.split(',')
    sentence = ' '.join(sep[0].split()[:-1])
    words = [sep[0].split()[-1], *sep[1:]]
    return ' '.join(f'{sentence} {w.strip()}' for w in words)

print(my_split(s))
print(my_split(s1))
```